# sql right join return multiple rows from right table

Tags: mysql, join, right-join

I have two tables products table and batch table. products table contains a list of products and batch table contains information on arrival date, expiry date, batch number and quantity. when recording to batch table i  pull product_id and store it on batch table. I want to query the two tables using right join, however I am not able to get the other rows from the batch table. here is my code

```
SELECT products.product_id, products.gen_name,products.product_code, batch.product_id FROM products RIGHT OUTER JOIN batch ON batch.product_id=products.product_id;
```

how can i also get arrival date, expiry date, batch number and quantity from the batch table?

Comment: Hard to say without seeing data, but you aren't querying arrival date, expiry date, and batch number in your select either. How do you know you're not getting rows? batch.product_id is null?

Comment: Have you tried making the primary pull from the batch table, and LEFT joining on the products table? I'm not 100% sure I understand your situation, but if you want all the records from the BATCH table, this may be a better choice. You may also have an issue with nulls in the existing RIGHT join. Maybe add a WHERE batch.productiD IS NOT NULL.

Comment: Here is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is hard to say without seeing table. I hope this might help you to solve your problem:
[SQL RIGHT JOIN](http://www.tutorialgateway.org/sql-right-join/)

Comment: The link helped me. Selecting all the rows did the work. changed my code to this `SELECT* FROM products RIGHT OUTER JOIN batch ON batch.product_id=products.product_id`

Answer (score 0):

> how can i also get arrival date, expiry date, batch number and
>   quantity from the batch table?

Add them to the select list.